# Check Sessions for Shopping Cart

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5

i have a specific issue about show add to cart.First of all i have the view in that way that the previous route is always the same,because you choose menu categories first and than goes to dishes so i cant check it.
I have 2 different ways of going to products. The first one is clicking the "Menu" in navigation bars and than open the dishes just as a gallery (without option of add to cart), the second one if choosing the products after completing the booking form and choose the menu you want in booking. So how can i disable add to cart option if i go directly from nav bars ????(because in both cases is the same view)
This is my controller:

```
public function index($id)
{
    $menu_categories = Menu_Categories::where('visible','yes')->where('delete','no')->orderBy('position','ASC')->get();
    $selected_menu = $id;
    $dishes = Dishes::where('visible','yes')->where('delete','no')->where('id_menu_category',$id)->orderBy('name','DESC')->get();

    return view('dishes.dishes', ['dishes' => $dishes,'menu_categories' => $menu_categories,'selected_menu' => $selected_menu]);
}


/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index_nav($id)
{
    $menu_categories = Menu_Categories::where('visible','yes')->where('delete','no')->orderBy('position','ASC')->get();
    $selected_menu = $id;
    $dishes = Dishes::where('visible','yes')->where('delete','no')->where('id_menu_category',$id)->orderBy('name','DESC')->get();
    session(['menu_nav' => true]);
    return view('dishes.dishes', ['dishes' => $dishes,'menu_categories' => $menu_categories,'selected_menu' => $selected_menu]);
}
```

And this is my view:

```
 @foreach($dishes as $dish)
                    <!-- shop item -->
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="home-product text-center position-relative overflow-hidden margin-ten no-margin-top">
                                <a href=""><img height="300" style="height:250px;width: 100%" src="{{$dish->image}}" alt=""/></a>
                                <span class="product-name text-uppercase  black-text" ><a style="font-weight: bold; background-color: #FFFFFF;border: 1px solid white">{{$dish->name}}</a></span>
                                <span class="price black-text">{{$dish->price}} €</span>


                                <div class="quick-buy" style="width:100px;height:100px;margin-left:150px;">
                                    <div class="product-share">
                                        @if(Session::has('manu_nav') &&  Session::get('manu_nav') == true)

                                        @else
                                            <a href="{{url('add_item_to_cart',$dish->id)}}" class="highlight-button-dark btn btn-small no-margin-right quick-buy-btn"  title=""><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></a>
                                        @endif
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- end shop item -->
                @endforeach
```

Comment: did not undestood your question .. can u edit or make it more clear ?

Comment: @FaisalMehmoodAwan hmmm is it ok now?

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario, setting a session from your controller has a problem. It will work for the current scenario, but the session has to remove.

Else even if they go from the menu bar, the session will be there and hence the add to cart option will be disabled here also since the blade file check for the session. One workaround is to remove this issue is by removing the session in your `index` method.

However laravel has a built in workaround for this called as [flash data](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/session#flash-data) in session.

```
$request->session()->flash('menu_nav', 'true');
```

This session will be only there for the first request and automatically reset when the page is reloaded. So you can trigger flash session in your `index_nav` method and check using your blade, which will be automatically unset when user goes to next page.